# Are Coset Effective Field Theories CFTs?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, effective-field-theory

The coset construction of the low energy effective action is a powerful way of understanding how theories with spontaneously broken symmetry behave at low energy, as it tells us what the essential ingredients are that make up the theory at low energy. This construction does not allow us however to have a precise evaluation of the effective action, without doing explicit calculations.

I understand that theories that have flowed to the IR become conformal (there may be exceptions to this like the Wilson-Fisher fixed point, but lets ignore those for now). If this is the case, does this imply that since the coset constructed effective action describes the lowest lying energy excitations, the action *must* obey conformal symmetry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general rule is that in the broken phase, you don't get a non-trivial CFT. Indeed, the coset effective actions depend on something dimensionful like the pion decay constant so they are not conformal. You can continue flowing to the IR, in which case interactions involving powers of $f_\pi$ will all be integrated out. This will give you a CFT but it will just be free with one free field for each Goldstone.