# Uniqueness of high temperature RG fixed point

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, effective-field-theory

Given a $\phi^4$ theory in $d<4$
$$S_{\Lambda} = \int d^dx \left[\frac{1}{2}(\partial_i \phi)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \mu_0^2 \phi^2 + \Lambda^{d-4} \tilde{g}_0 \phi^4  \right]\,,$$
the corresponding RG flows in the coupling space are qualitatively like the ones shown in the picture. The question is whether the high Temperature fixed point, which corresponds to $\xi=0$, is unique. For example, do the vertical lines emanating from the Gaussian f.p. and the Wilson-Fisher f.p. both lead to a (high temperature) fixed point, and if so, do they meet at some point?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/649670 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/650507

Comment: Can you please give a link to the book where the picture is taken from?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0610018

Comment: the picture looks familiar :)

Comment: What is $\xi$? It's not in your action.

Comment: the correlation length, usually given by $\xi \sim 1/m$